# Best way to use Bootstrap with Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

After some research I have the choice between two ways of integrating Bootstrap into Django.

1. https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit
2. https://github.com/earle/django-bootstrap

The first one requires some changes in your templates, the second one requires changes in your views.

**Example for 1.)**

*[...]{{ form|as_bootstrap }}[...]*

```
{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}

<form action="/url/to/submit/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|as_bootstrap }}
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Example for 2.)**

*[...]class LoginForm(BootstrapForm)[...]*

```
from bootstrap.forms import BootstrapForm, Fieldset

class LoginForm(BootstrapForm):
    class Meta:
        layout = (
            Fieldset("Please Login", "username", "password", ),
        )

    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), max_length=100)
```

Which way is recommended? Or any other method?

Answer (score 11):

If it's just about the forms, maybe you want to have a look at django-crispy-forms, too.
It's the successor of django-uni-form and supports bootstrap forms.

https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms